# How do I see my mobile contacts in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

In Pidgin and most other clients for instant messaging I've used, when my contact is logged in from a mobile phone, the client shows an icon by their name so I can differentiate between these buddies that are online from a phone and buddies that are online from a computer. Does Empathy have this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547658) in Empathy and is currently being [worked on](http://ubuntutrap.blogspot.com/2010/08/empathy-you-redesign-contact-entry.html).

So Empathy currently lacks this feature but it will likely show up in the next version of Ubuntu (10.10).

Comment: The bug has been fixed. In 12.04 you can see the icon by the contact's names when he is logged from a mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just yet. This feature is coming, likely in 10.10, and there was a blog post asking users about how this should be presented, so if you feel like it, you can give your opinion [here](http://ubuntutrap.blogspot.com/2010/08/empathy-you-redesign-contact-entry.html).